# Add Content to Content()

Tags: plugins, pages, users, content

**The Question**:::
This is a strange question but I need to add content to `content()` in `page.php`. How do I do this?

**The Why**:::
You see there's a plugin that uses the [plugin id="1337"] and I am linking this id with user ID so the  ID needs to be dynamic and then added to the content of the page. This way each user will see something different from the plugin it will be cool I swear.

I tried added it directly to the html but no luck it has to be added to `content()` somehow. No luck finding anything online either.

**Installation**::: I'm running wordpress version 3.2.1 and using the TwentyEleven Theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Hook into the_content filter here
function append_to_the_content($content){
    ob_start();
    // Start doing stuff here ...

    // End doing stuff here ...
    $new_content = ob_get_clean();
    return $content.$new_content; // Append new content
    return $new_content.$content; // Prepend new content
} // function append_to_the_content($content)
// 11 priority avoid wpautop() that messes custom HTML
add_filter('the_content', 'append_to_the_content', 11);
```

Regards.

Comment: Great! I appericiate your help. I'm getting an `unexpected T_FUNCTION` @ `add_filter()` line. Do I still need `content` before this or is your code replacing it? Because with it there or not it still gets that syntax error. For what it's worth I'm using 2011theme

Comment: I used PHP 5.3 Anonymous functions. If you run 5.2, use the new version. I updated the code.

Comment: Ok cool, syntax errors are gone. I'm echo(ing) out my values between the `ob_start()` and `$new_content` and it shows my page just fine, but without content. I do need to echo right?

Comment: If you echo '[append this]'; between start and end doing stuff, it will be appended to the content, unless you use the second return. If you don't see anything, it means you have another filter somewhere that does not return anything. This code is tested and works. (or paste your code here and I'll check it out)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just realized I was using both returns so I commented out the second return but still no luck. I put my code in pastebin for ease http://pastebin.com/rHfvmpMs

Comment: @Howdy_McGee You _should_ move your fn to your functions.php file.

Comment: Oh God! Didn't realize you're no pro. My code must be placed, as @kaiser said, in functions.php for a Theme or in a Plugin in /wp-content/plugins/. Not inline! It's plugin code.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Your code looks nice, so no "you're not a pro" issue. Point also is that you don't need the `ob_start();` and `ob_get_clean();` functions. Just move your function to your functions.php file and add whatever you want to add to `$new_content;`. Then append or prepend it to `$content` with `$content = $content.$new_content;` and `return $content;`. That's enough for your filter to work. Oh, and place `if ( ! is_page() return $content;` as first line in your function to avoid the appending if you're not on a page.

Comment: Appending is a joke for any complex construct inside the the_content filter. Teach him something proper, not bending over backwards to append strings when OB does just that allowing any level of complexity within the actual filter code.

Comment: Yeah I am definetly not a pro, just a guy that knows a little php, html and wordpress to get by. I still can't get it to return anything, at this point I cant even add content through wp-admin. Here's what I got in fucntions.php
`function append_to_the_content($content)
  {
   if ( ! is_page()) 
    return $content;
   $new_content = "stuff";
   return $content.$new_content;
  }`

and heres what's in my content-page.php
`add_filter('the_content', 'append_to_the_content', 11);`

of course both in php tags and such. Maybe there's a better way to go about this...

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Your error is elsewhere. Remove this new filter code entirely and tell me if content is output properly.

Comment: Yeah, once I add `the_content()` back in, everything is fine. So what am I looking for now a filter elsewhere? That could be anywhere :/

Comment: OH GOD! You never remove the the_content(). NEVER! Listen: you leave the the_content() call where it is in the page.php (or whatever) code and go to your functions.php and paste my code on top of everything, right under the <?php tag! DO IT! Just do it :) The code I gave you here alters the the_content() output. But the_content() still needs to be called in your theme. TRY IT (then rate my answer and efforts)! ;)

Comment: @EarnestoDev Pretty aggressive behavior... not going to argue with you. What fancy stuff do you imagine the OP could do, that makes output buffering required? I maybe would understand it if you'd be using it in the template with a callback, but I'm curious what wouldn't be possible to be appended when not using the buffering _inside_ the filter.

Comment: Ohhh man that was my problem, missing content call.

 See what I'm doing with this content change is I have some protected pages and when logged in members get to see their gallery. The problem is that it shows All galleries not member specific. So now I'm going to compare userID with galleryID and make 1 univeral page that will place content based off of that. So I needed a dynamic gallery ID, but the plugin requires it to be put in the page content like `[plugin id='1']`. In theory it sounds good so I'm running with it. Thanks for all your help! I appreciate it greatly. Cant upvote enough